# onclick on link should open unopen tabbed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have horizontal tabbed structure, which has 4 tabs and ALL is by default opened, as per this Screenshot:

[image]

Now my questions is,

**What I want is**

*Suppose i have one dummy.html page on which i have one link called 'Travel tab', When i click on that link i will redirect to this tabbed contained page called offer.aspx where i want Travel tab should open by default.*

Please find the code of tabbed structure on offers.aspx :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
        $('.newboxes').each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
                $(this).show(0);
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide(0);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div style="height: 30px;">

<div style="padding: 5px; float: left; color: #666;">
    <a id="myHeader1" class="bmark active" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');">All</a><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<div style="padding: 5px; float: left; color: #666;">
    <a id="myHeader2" class="bmark" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');">Travel</a><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<div style="padding: 5px; float: left; color: #666;">
    <a id="myHeader3" class="bmark" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');">Shopping</a><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<div style="padding: 5px; float: left; color: #666;">
    <a id="myHeader5" class="bmark" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes5');">Value Added Services</a>
</div>
```

```
<div>
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="display: block; padding: 20px 5px 5px 5px; width: auto;">
</div>
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="display: block; padding: 20px 5px 5px 5px; width: auto;">
</div>
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="display: block; padding: 20px 5px 5px 5px; width: auto;">
</div>
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes5" style="display: block; padding: 20px 5px 5px 5px; width: auto;">
</div>
```

Comment: "Now my questions is," I don't see any question

Comment: Add a fragment to the URL of the tab, eg `page.html#travel` then use `window.location.hash` to select the chosen tab.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Can you explain in more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use hash in this case.

In your link, you do something like that, using your content's id:

```
<a href="offer.aspx#newboxes1">Travel</a>
```

In your offer.aspx page, you look for the hash:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');

    // Check if it has something
    if (hash != '') { 
        showonlyone(hash); 

        // Highlight the correct tab, triggering the event that does that :)
        var index = hash.replace('newboxes', ''); 
        $('#myHeader' + index).trigger('click'); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Show the value of hash in a console.log and see if it has the correct value, please. If it has, your function should do the rest. :)

Comment: I am getting error as `ReferenceError: hash is not defined`

Comment: Did you put that console.log line after var hash = window.location.hash; ?

Comment: please explain in detail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68338/discussion-between-everton-lenger-and-rahul-sutar).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to pass a parameter via url, in this case the requested id, from `dummy.html` and grab it in `offer.aspx`

In your dummy.html

```
<a href="offer.aspx?id='newboxes2'">Travel tab</a>
```

In your offer.aspx, grab the id from the url and store it in the DOM (let's say on the wrapper div of your tabs):

```
<%
Response.Write "<div id="wrapper" data-id='>" & Request.QueryString("id") & "'>"
%>

    <!-- tabs -->
</div>
```

and then grab the data-id with jquery:

```
var id = $('#wrapper').data('id');

function showonlyone(id) {
    $('.newboxes').each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == id) {
            $(this).show(0);
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hi john, where to write the `<%
Response.Write "<div id="wrapper" data-id='>" & Request.QueryString("id") & "'>"
%>` code ? getting bit of confused..!

Comment: In the page where you hold your tabs

Comment: `"<div id="wrapper" data-id='>" & Request.QueryString("id") & "'>"` is giving syntax error as `;` expected

Answer (score 0):

Set you dummy.html page links like this

dummy.html Page:

```
<a href="sample.html#travel" >Travel</a>
<a href="sample.html#shopping">Shopping</a>
```

Sample Page:

```
<div id='travel'>Travel</div>
<div id='shopping'>Shopping</div>
```

then when you click on Travel or Shopping link it should redirect to Sample page's desired tab

As you are using ASP.NET you should try something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" onclick="RunServerSideMethod_Click">Travel</asp:HyperLink>
```

and your server side  method:

```
protected void RunServerSideMethod_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code which needs to be executed on serverside
       Response.Redirect("page.aspx" + "#here", false);


    }
```

Comment: Hi Aminul, But it doesnt provide me any click on `Travel` Link, it displaying like a simple text